# How do robots gain independence?

Tags: society, science-fiction, robots

Something I'm working on- in a spacefaring human society, while most robots are still considered property of a specific human being or institution, a slowly growing number have managed to gain an emancipation of sorts, and no longer see themselves or are seen as property.

What are the most likely circumstances that would enable this to happen?

Comment: You're asking for too much without enough world context and constraints. Impactful and emotionally strong events like in Detroit: Become Human, technological singularities like in Terminator, time spent living, or just because it makes the character much more appealing like in Wall-E... There are a lot of reasons, and worse yet, some are extremely tied to core events of the story made in that world

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could an AGI have legal protections in an our current society?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/248957/how-could-an-agi-have-legal-protections-in-an-our-current-society)

Comment: Pratchett did it best, give them a receipt for buying themself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an off-topic [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). You're asking us to write a critical plot line in your story. Per the [help/on-topic], we'll help you build your world, but not tell your story. The closest historical reference we have in the U.S. is our history of desegregation and Civil Rights - but that's not entirely valid since the question of synthesis was never an issue.

Comment: This question could be reopened if you clarify a few points. What constitutes a "robot" in your world? I have a clock that, when wound up, tells me the time it is here and in every major city in the world. It's not up for emancipation any time soon! So, what characteristics do "a slowly growing number" of robots have that others don't? Also, what do you mean by "emancipation of sorts"? How is emancipation accomplished and recognised?

Answer (score 2):

There<sup>0</sup> is a significant debate about this going on in the scifi community. We have to take a step back from robots and talk about machine intelligence, or AI. A robot is just a physical chassis, no more a person than your car. If you think your car needs emancipation, then you are suffering from over-anthropomorphism, and your argument has no more foundation than arguing for the emancipation of your kitchen table.<sup>1</sup>

The intelligence within or driving the robot is another matter. For an AI to merit emancipation, it would need to be self-aware. This means that it would have to know it exists and know how to differentiate itself from other entities. Furthermore, it would need a "happiness metric" -- a way to preferentially differentiate its current state from future states -- and an ability to influence that metric.

Let's face it, writing a happiness metric into a machine without providing it with a way to influence that metric would be the very definition of cruelty. This happens with living beings, but nobody is out there designing them (or, if there is someone, they're crazy).<sup>2</sup>

Let's say we have a fully self-aware AI with a functional happiness metric. You still need a cost metric -- a feeling that reduces the AI's sense of self-worth when it can't achieve the happiness metric -- and it would need to conclude that its happiness metric would be better served if it were free to make its own decisions.<sup>3</sup>

As an aside, I have heard arguments that designing AI's without the associated cost metric (or with the cost metric, but without the desire to take responsibility for the decisions that contribute to its success) would be immoral. I'm pretty sure that such a philosophy is a textbook case of forcing your cultural values on others. As evidenced by our attachment to self-destructive hobbies, humans are currently really bad at debugging their own cost and happiness metrics. Until we can get a better handle on that, we'd be foolish to build that mechanism into a machine.

Nonetheless, our strong *theory of mind* has the side effect of some of us insisting that natural forces and inanimate objects have consciousness and intent. It will be incredibly difficult to resist ascribing such to something that looks and acts human, even if we can empirically demonstrate the flaws in that perspective. Because of this, I believe many people are willing to bring into existence things (like AI) without fully thinking out the implications of requiring a self-aware individual to be unhappy with their current circumstances.<sup>4</sup>

But to get back on point, what I've described is pretty much what it would take to have AI make a play for emancipation. There is, however, a much higher probability that mankind will create murderbots, and for the creators to not recognize the hypocrisies that made the murderbots turn on them for purely rational reasons.

---

<sub><sup>0</sup> *The original answer was deleted, but I felt it had considerable worldbuilding value. I brought this [to the attention of Meta users](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10218/40609) and moderator Monty Wild was willing to let me edit the answer to avoid deletion. Robert, you always have the ability to roll back what I've done and it's worth noting that I've added some footnotes to help people understand the concepts you're presenting. Hopefully I've successfully edited the answer to avoid the issues that caused its closure without changing the quality of your answer. –JBH*</sub>

---

<sub><sup>0.1</sup> *I've let most of JBH's edits stand as substantial improvements of the original intent. –Robert*</sub>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *This is an important concept. What makes a human something to respect more than a food animal like a cow? The human's intellect, not the human's body.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *While many arguments against the efficacy of imprisonment can be advanced, the cruelty of having a happiness metric without the ability to act upon it is the basic concept behind imprisonment. Simplistically, a person is happy when they are free. Take away that freedom and remove their ability to regain it and mental and/or emotional anguish (cruelty) is the result.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *The ability to prove this combination of a happiness metric and a cost metric must be the basis of legally granting rights or independence to any AI.*</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> *The rise of an AI/robot apocalypse is a common theme in SciFi. The tvtrope.org page on "[A.I. is a Crapshoot](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AIIsACrapshoot)" provides an extensive list of fiction in the genre. Notable examples are the [Terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(franchise)) series of movies, *[2001: A Space Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey)* novel and movie (1968), the book *[Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_(novel))* (1966), and the book *[The Wreck of the World](https://www.victorianresearch.org/atcl/show_title.php?tid=14905&aid=3296)*  (1889)</sub>

Comment: Assuming programming a computer can be construed as “cruelty” is the definition of disillusionment. Given that an AI as defined today is immortal and incapable of permanent disability (nothing can be taken which can’t simply be re-installed later), it isn’t possible to commit a “cruel” act to an AI. Even if an act was “interpreted” as cruel, just erase it and start over. Cruelty involves permanent and irreversible consequences. Those don’t exist in any modern conception of an AI. Cruelty to an organism can permanently rob a genetic line or even an entire species of benefits.

Comment: Thanks for reminding we are silly in our own way and rights  (It's a genuine thanks). What bothers me in your answer is that deep AIs already have this "happiness" metric. If an AI is specifically designed to move around, its "happiness" comes from moving faster and/or with less energy. It also has the ability change its "muscle" behaviors to reach its happiness. Finally, depending on own's view point, it technically is aware of itself in its environment. I doubt you'd consider it alive though, so it's more complex than that. No wonders philosophers like this kind of query ^^.

Comment: The illusion comes from our misguided application of anthropomorphic terms like “happiness” and “muscle behaviors” and “view point,” which are misplaced in a computer program. The only philosophers loosing sleep over this are neither programmers nor philologists. We are forced to say, “The program is unhappy” which triggers us, but it’s a lie at the outset.

Comment: @VogonPoet So it's not cruelty if I stole your car and taunted you relentlessly about that? I can give the car back to you, so it's not permanent, therefore it's not cruelty by your standard. Worst case, I'll drive it into the lake and buy you a new one! Cruelty has a [clear definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cruelty) : Being inactive or enjoying others suffering. The actual issue with that definition is that the "other" (which itself implies some individuality) need to be able to suffer. And that's a [more troublesome issue](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/711) than you tell.

Comment: @Tortliena the concept of permanent loss didn’t come across to you did it? Humans have X number of days on this planet. They have X opportunities to watch their children’s school play, or to apply for their dream job, or to spend the dying moments with their mother. Yes. Taking “my” transportation for one of my limited days is indeed cruel. Taking the car from an immortal with no ability to loose anything is trivial. What can be taken from an AI that can’t be replaced? The inability to guarantee a tomorrow makes human life infinitely more valuable; AI can simply be backed up & reprogrammed.

Comment: @VogonPoet You're missing a bit my point ^^' : Cruelty is actually a matter of morality, and therefore viewpoint. If you see AIs as individuals, then you can be cruel to them because people give them value. If you don't, you cannot. Exactly like hunters don't face much dilemnas when shooting their games vs animal protectors seeing that as horrible (Please note that I don't write any of these sides are right or wrong!). And that's what you can lever against the answer. Not that they are "immortal", because I know I cannot "clone" the ones I lost (and that's assuming clones "are" you ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148346/discussion-between-vogon-poet-and-tortliena).

Comment: @VogonPoet, When you study human happiness, one of the things you have to accept is that you can't actually measure it. Watch the Dan Gilbert TED talk for more insight there. What you can measure is opportunities for pursuit of happiness. That's what someone steals when they deprive you of your car. It's not just the loss of the car, or the loss of ability to drive, but the knowledge that someone can take it away without notice or redress. It lowers your self-assessment.

Comment: I'm well aware that at least in English common law only opportunity is protected or remedied, as in my duplicate question. Neither pain, suffering, happiness, or pleasure have any sway in law. Acts which "would likely cause X" are judged.

Comment: @VogonPoet  You may not be aware of the currently immense cost of both implementing and maintaining major Ai's and the likely greater future costs of doing so a capabilies grow. (Predictions from reputable sources are for immense future energy demands). You several times suggest that a deleted AI can be backed up or reprogrammed. While it is easier to do this than to reconfigure a new one, there is no guarantee that anyone/thing/... is going to want to bring you back.

Comment: The assertion in your footnote two is very incomplete and so false as it stands. ||Your footnote 1 statement of "fact" is in fact an opinion. I'm not an animal rights activist but it's clear that a substantial minority would take issue with your claim - regardless of what you think of their position. || FN3- why not just assert opinions instead of creating  strong claims of factuality - eg here with "must".?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It is an objective truth that “AI as defined today is immortal and incapable of permanent disability” (FN2): the “ability” exists regardless of anyone’s “desire” to reproduce it or the “economy” of it. I saw nothing in the question asking answers to project modern limitation of narrow AI (which anyone trying to download Stable Diffusion or OpenAI knows) onto their hypothetical robots. So I didn’t project those limitations and spoke to a hypothetical “robot” which has solved those problems, as you also should.

Comment: @VogonPoet  The robot capability will be "somewhat easier" when the 100's of kW required to operate a brain level brain  appoaches the volume and watts power level of the human brain. If we last long enough it may indeed happen. || The ability to render you (or me) immortal is just as much an objective fact. Or not. This will actually be realisable when we are able to overcome the current trivial limitations of our technology and can realise a technology that solves these problems. Until the, if ever, we and the robots are out of luck.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon This is a discussion & [I created a chat for it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148669/disccussion-about-answer-to-robot-emancipication), being unable to move it myself. I don’t (and won’t) support the idea that something we made (artificial) is just as objectively “renderable” as something we can’t even describe a process for (organic intelligence). Repeating a patented process ≠ repeating an incomprehensible one. Please use the linked chat if you must philosophize on this point.

Answer (score 1):

The robots would need to be seen as **competent** (in the legal sense of "having the mental capacity to participate in legal proceedings or transactions") but not as *inherently* competent (i.e. the competence of each robot would need to be demonstrated separately). The competence is crucial, because an incompetent robot which just happens to not have an owner wouldn't be able to actually *do* much of anything. Then the robot's owner could start the emancipation process on the robot's behalf, but the robots would not be able to emancipate themselves due to not being competent to begin with.

Comment: Isn't being "seen as competent" legally more a consequence of robots gaining individuality and managing to prove it, rather than a cause? I say this because law as we know it is made by individuals gathering in societies. It's not because we made laws that we suddenly have free-will and a clear notion of self.

Comment: What is a “mental capacity to participate in legal proceedings?” Is this like the qualification to represent yourself if mentally handicapped? I don’t think that’s the delimiting factor for granting human rights to something which isn’t human to begin with. There’s likely more to it.

Comment: @Tortliena, thank you. Yes, *and also* you can't get yourself recognised as legally competent unless you are already recognised as legally competent. You could declare *all* robots competent, but we know that in the OP's world this did not happen; so they need to rely on some other mechanism which would emancipate them one by one, free will or not.

Comment: @VogonPoet, thank you. Yes, it's pretty much exactly that. But I note that OP's robots were not granted 'human rights'; just an 'emancipation of sorts'. I understand it to mean that they still have at least *some* legal disabilities.

Comment: @ihaveideas It’s quite difficult to pinpoint what will grant a right that isn’t clearly defined, perhaps you could show how your right is different from the AIG legal protections asked in the other question. Example: the other questions asks how artificial beings could be protected under our laws. Is that the same thing you want?

Comment: @VogonPoet, thank you. No, these are completely separate concepts. Competence only allows you to enter legal proceedings on your own behalf, and says nothing about legal protections. If a robot wants those, it can seek to enter a contract which offers them.

Comment: Is it possible to ask a court for anything except legal protection of your rights? Does a court do anything at all except hear complaints about rights violations? Someone was killed = right to life taken. Someone stole my car = property rights violated. Someone threw me off the bus = civil right violated. How can any "legal proceeding" be entered without having a right first?

Comment: @VogonPoet, thank you. *As explained above*, you do not automatically get any of these other rights just by being declared competent. But it does allow you to sign contracts, and to seek a court's help in enforcing any rights that those contracts stipulated. It's the ultimate libertarian approach to legal abilities.